# How to insert and retrieve an image from mysql database using spring mvc framework?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller

How to insert and retrieve an image from mysql database using spring mvc framework?

Sorry i don't know how to upload my entire problem here. 
So Kindly post your email address then i ll send as RAR file immediately. Or else any body  explain how upload the tutorials in this website.

My Email ID : **srisnath@gmail.com**. Mention the Question(Which i given as a title) in the Subject column and send it. I've solved this problem as product maintaining systems. So those who need send me a mail. I ll upload it. Thank you.

Sri

Comment: try to convert into byte and persist in the database.

Comment: Ideally, your question should contain a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). You don't have to upload your complete application, just the parts of the source code that are related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **blob** datatype for your image.Here is the sample [link](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring/insert-image-using-spring-jdbctemplate) for your requirements.And the other way is changing image into **byte** data and store it into your database with byte datatype.But I personally not recommended storing image into database.